# Can I use both HTTP and HTTPS in nginx upstream?

Tags: http, nginx, https

I have Nginx config as below:

```
upstream staging {
    server myappstaging.somedomain.com;
}

upstream prod {
    server myapp.somedomain.com:443;
}

# map to different upstream backends based on header
map $http_x_server_select $pool {
    default "prod";
    staging "staging";
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://$pool;
    }
}
```

I want to forward requests with `x-server-select` header set to staging to `http://myappstaging.somedomain.com` and for prod to `https://myapp.somedomain.com:443`

Is it possible do that with Nginx ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the scheme as part of your variable.

For example:

```
map $http_x_server_select $pool {
    default "https://prod";
    staging "http://staging";
}
```

And:

```
proxy_pass $pool;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly different need. My need is to be taken either one or the other in a balance, by not considering the default one as a priority.

I notice while having a similar mapping like yours

```
map $http_x_server_select $pool {
default "https://prod";
staging "http://staging";
}
```

it is always picking the default one.

I played with this config and I replaced the `default` by a particular name e.g. `prod`:

```
map $http_x_server_select $pool {
prod "https://prod";
staging "http://staging";
}
```

but `$pool` doesn't have any value as I tried to print it in the logs.

By having no `default` value, it seems `$pool` value is always empty in the logs.

How may I have no default value, but in the same time whatever is being configured for the `$pool` entries will be picked in any moment of time by no particular order?